# Forcing ASP.Net to use TCP/IP to connect to SQL Server instead of named pipes

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-3.5

How can I force my ASP.Net application to connect to a SQL Server using TCP/IP, not Named Pipes?

I read somewhere putting "tcp:" in front of the server name in the connectionstring should do the trick, but it does not seem to change anything.

#### Edit1:

- TCP/IP is enabled on the SQL Server.
- I tried Network Library=dbmssocn in the connectionstring, I still get an errormessage about named pipes: "provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server"

#### Edit2:

- Turns out my problem was another hidden connectionstring used by entity framework

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can force it in the connection string:

```
server=tcp:hostname
```

Via: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/sql-force-the-protocol-tcp-named-pipes-etc-in-your-connection-string.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use the SQL Server Configuration Manager on the client and disable the client protocols you don't want it to use.

Comment: By client machine, do you mean the web server? That does not even have SQL Server installed.

Comment: I mean the client machine.  You can install just the connectivity components.  Or you can disable namedpipes on the server.  Eitherway you'll end up connecting by TCP.

Comment: This solution doesn't provide an answer programmatically and it doesn't work if a developer doesn't have access to the GUI on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you're connecting to the database, but [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) should give the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a quick hint, could cause issues, if you need to specify a port, do it after the IP address, and use a comma, not a colon.