# Cannot access SQL server instance from SSRS Report Designer - Named Pipe error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014, report-designer

I have the following setup configuration for SSRS:

1. Sql Server 2014 running on VPS1. Protocol enabled: TCPIP
2. SSRS 2014 installed on VPS2, and configured to access SQL Server ReportServer database from VPS1
3. Reports from SSRS use a shared data source which use SQL Authentication, to connect to databases from VPS1 for data for reports. All reports are working ok, I can open and run them in browser when accessing on http://vps2/reportserver
4. I need to edit the reports: to edit sql query to add fields, etc. So I'm opening them in Report Builder (either installed stand-alone, or from web interface at http://vps2/reports and select 
   **Edit in Report Builder**
   [image]
5. When the report is opened in Report Builder, I can run it, and it runs just fine
   [image]
6. If I test datasource connection, it works fine also:
   [image]
7. However, when I try to edit the query behind a dataset, I'm asked for user / pass for connection, I enter sql server auth info, then I get the error:
   [image]

Why is Report Designer trying to connect to database using named pipes, when SSRS and SQL server are on different machines, named pipes are not even enabled on SQL protocols, and testing datasource connection and running the report actually work just fine?

Please offer some ideas, I'm stuck with this issue, being impossible to update any reports.

Comment: Maybe try changing your connection string to force tcp first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983605/forcing-asp-net-to-use-tcp-ip-to-connect-to-sql-server-instead-of-named-pipes, just to rule out that. But I think maybe the named pipes error is just a by product of the authentication error. Perhaps take a peek in your sql server logs and see if there is any more information about the connection failure.

Comment: enable your TCP/IP,VIA,Named Pipes in Sql Server Configuration manager

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: My datasource conenction works ok, when tested (see point 6). So what connection string should I change to force TCP?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted. You'd need to edit the connection string in the actual shared connection

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far was to setup a VPN, and access the SSRS from Reports Designed using internal IP over VPN